# iOS device not receiving push notification after updated app from GCM to FCM

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugin-fcm

I recently updated my app from GCM to FCM and it was working fine if I installed latest app with out updating the existing one. If I update the app then device not getting push notification. As per server it saying the push sent successfully but device not getting the push notification.

Server Response
[Server Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME1pK.png)

Observations :

1. iOS : when I update the app from GCM to FCM I am getting a new token.
2. Android : If I update the app from GCM to FCM, still the token remains same.

After updating the app on launch function I am calling the below lines,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]; 
[FIRApp configure];
[self connectToFcm];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                             name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
```

In the above code the token refresh was getting triggered and getting a new FCM token.

```
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);
   [FCMPlugin.fcmPlugin notifyOfTokenRefresh:refreshedToken];
   [self connectToFcm];
}
```

Is there any flag need to set to make it work in iOS when updating app from GCM to FCM?

Note : By deleting the instanceID I am getting a new token, with that token the device able to get the push.

Old App : with GCM token -  Working
New App : With FCM token - Working
Update App : From GCM token - FCM token - Not Working

Comment: Token remains same in android because FCM is backwards compatible.